# Как показывать адреса вместо имен в MS Outlook?

Tags: outlook

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ в Outlook вместо имен отображать e-mail адреса? В настройках не нашел, гугл тоже не дал ответа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]